# Working with user defined variables in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I have below set statements for MSSQL, which works perfect :

```
Declare @uid INT;
Declare @ct int;
Declare @code int;
Declare @usertype int;
Declare @flag char;
Declare @max_itemid int;
Declare @ulname varchar(10);
Declare @ufname varchar(10);
set @code= 123;
set @ulname='Will';
set @ufname='Smith';
set @max_itemid=(select max(itemid) from registration;

set @uid = (select uid  from users where ulname=@ulname and ufname=@ufname)

set @ct=(select count(*) from usercodes where itemId=@uid)
set @usertype=(select usertype from users where uid=@uid)

If(@usertype=1)
begin
If (@uid>0)
Begin 
    select * from users where uid=@uid; 
    select * from usercodes where itemId=@uid;

        if(@ct=0)
        begin
            if (@max_itemid=2 or @max_itemid=0)
            set @flag='D';
            else 
            set @flag='O';

        insert into usercodes (itemId,CODE,Flag) values(@uid,@code,@flag);
        select * from usercodes where itemId=@uid;

        else
        begin
            PRINT 'UserCode is already added and below is result:';
            select * from usercodes where itemId=@uid;
        end

end
Else
    PRINT 'No User Found';

end

else
  begin
    print 'User not added as usertype is ';PRINT  @usertype;
end
```

Now i am a newbee to Mysql and want to rewrite the above statements as per the Mysql conventions. I figured out the syntax, and changes the declarations as :

```
SET @CODE='S10_12345' ;
SET @NAME='Will Smith';
```

and so on.
But the executions stops once it enters the IF statement. Can someone help figuring out where I am wrong ?

P.S. I am not using any procedures/functions - i can't store these bunch of statements as I have to customize the select statements as the DB can change each time.

Comment: MySQL uses `if . . . then . . . end if`, Not `if begin . . . end`.

Comment: thanks @GordonLinoff. Corrected it but still doesn't work - just curious to know if flow control works outside of stored programs (procedures,triggers) ? i.e without using stored programs